# Angularjs uib-collapse behaviour to table colums hide and show

Tags: angularjs

In bootstrap uib-collapse class animation behaviour hapeens only for vertical div.
But I need same animation/motion behaviour for table columns to show or hide upon click on icon.

For rightnow using ng-show and ng-hide but that doesnt seems animation behaviour not look good.

How can I achieve same behaviour for table colum wise NOT row

Answer (score 0):

uib-collapse has a horizontal option and all you have to do is to add an additional attribute called 'horizontal' for the panel div as follows.

```
<div uib-collapse="isCollapsed" horizontal></div>
```

Comment: I just added css values the default updated to below thing..collapse.in{
        display: table-cell;
    }

Comment: I dont think so we need horizontal required here , but still the UI rendering is not good ,it is moving the table cells while collapse & un-collapse

Answer (score 0):

There is an [issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4358) recalling this problem and there is a workaround for it but as it's mentioned it's not recommended to use that.

> Doing some further investigation, this appears to be a longstanding pre-existing issue with animating tr elements - my recommendation is to not do it. It seems that even when using vanilla Bootstrap JS, one has to hack around it too.
>
> Here is a workaround that works - I am going to close this issue as not a fixable bug unfortunately. Thankfully, one can work around this, as my Plunker shows.

Comment: Thanks for sharing , but my issue is with column to hide and show NOT row wise(column level plus symbol will be there and then with minus it hides) , Looks like we don't have support for it and I need to add extra js file for this feature.